# I had a use engine put in my car but it still won't start up I have 2018 chev equinox Lt

Tags: starting, chevrolet, equinox

I have a engine replace in my 2018 chev equinox the car still won't crank but I found out the mechanic cut my engine harness and reattach it in stead of using my original harness will this cause the problem or do my key need to be programmed to new engine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you add a photo of the location of the cut harness?

Answer (score 0):

If the "mechanic" actually cut the harness, it could ABSOLUTELY cause the engine not to start. I would have no clue why they'd do that, because having to reconnect all of those wires correctly would take HOURS when just disconnecting the harness only takes 5-10 minutes. There are literally hundreds of wires going through a harness. Get the right wires mixed up in the reconnect and you are at a no start situation. If the "mechanic" thought they were actually taking easy street to just cut the harness, they really have no business being in this business. Personally, I'd make them pay for an entire new harness for your vehicle. There was no problems with your harness before they butchered it and what they did was a self-imposed problem ... they deserve to pay the cost of this.

**NOTE:** The reason why I put "mechanic" in quotes is because if someone did this, they really aren't a mechanic and as I've already stated, should not be doing this type of work.